# Back-up solution for Xserve + Xserve RAID?

Tags: backup, mac, tape, xserve

I've got an Apple Xserve, connected to a 10TB Xserve RAID.  I've also got several other Windows-based servers, and file servers, in the same rack.

My current tape back-up solution runs on a Windows server, and it doesn't play nice with my Mac server.  There are files not getting backed-up, failed back-ups, missing/corrupted files, etc.

Ideally, I'd be doing weekly or bi-monthly (twice a month) incremental back-ups.

I am looking for some kind of tape backup solution that I can dedicate just to the Mac stuff (i.e. keep my current set up for the Windows servers, and buy new software + equipment just for the Mac).

What would be the best, reasonably priced, software & hardware combo for this?

Comment: What kind of backup hardware do you have now? What backup software are you running?  Generally speaking if you have a backup environment & it supports Macs I would try to make that work rather than setting up something independent -- perhaps your vendor can help?

Comment: In theory, it supports Macs.  In practice, not so much.  We've had a lot of people (highly paid consultants) look at our set up, and they have been unable to get it working properly with our Mac.  So, I'd like to dedicate a back-up system just to the Mac.  I figure it will be cheaper than paying the consultants to repeatedly come out.  Also, in the future, our Mac may be in a different location than it is currently, so a dedicated back up system would be ideal, regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an Xserve that is backed up to a drobo, which is pretty easy to setup, used Carbon Copy Cloner for setting up scheduled backups.